# How to add 2 temporary tables together

Tags: sql, mysql, temp-tables

If I am creating temporary tables, that have 2 columns. `id` and `score`. I want to to add them together.

The way I want to add them is if they each contain the same `id` then I do not want to duplicate the `id` but instead add the scores together.

if I have 2 temp tables called `t1` and `t2`

and `t1` had:

```
id 3 score 4
id 6 score 7
```

and `t2` had:

```
id 3 score 5
id 5 score 2
```

I would end up with a new temp table containing:

```
id 3 score 9
id 5 score 2
id 6 score 7
```

The reason I want to do this is, I am trying to build a product search. I have a few algorithms I want to use, 1 using fulltext another not. And I want to use both algorithms so I want to create a temporary table based on algorithm1 and a temp table based on algorithm2. Then combine them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT id, SUM(score) AS score FROM (
  SELECT id, score FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, score FROM t2
) t3
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You will need to alias the nested select though and there's a mistake in the brackets

Comment: @Brendan: You got the syntax right, but Tom got the UNION ALL right.  Go teamwork!

Comment: Yes the system works, but then who deserves the accepted answer!?!?

Comment: @Brendan the system doesn't really work -- your answer is getting the up votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is untested but you should be able to perform a union on the two tables and then perform a select on the results, grouping the fields and adding the scores

```
SELECT id,SUM(score) FROM
(
    SELECT id,score FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,score FROM t2
) joined
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: you must use UNION ALL in case an entry in exists in t1 and t2 with the same id and score.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a full outer join on the ID. Select on the ID and the sum of the two "score" columns after coalescing the values to 0.

Comment: Correct - except I don't think MySQL supports full outer joins. You'd have to union a right and a left join.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, sum(score)
from (
 select * from table 1
 union all
 select * from table2
) tables
group by id
```

Comment: hmm, you guys are fast... but mine is correct.

Brendan you need to use UNION ALL

tom you ahev a syntax error and you need to alias the subquery

Comment: you highlight the code, then click the button that looks like binary code.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, SUM(score) FROM
(
    SELECT id, score FROM #t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, score FROM #t2
) AS Temp
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an union of those two tables then You can easily group the results.

```
SELECT id, sum(score) FROM 

(
 SELECT id, score FROM t1
 UNION 
 SELECT id, score FROM t2
) as tmp
GROUP BY id;
```